# Free online resource for transcripts of 草双紙

Tags: discussion, resources

草双紙 have gotten my interest recently however due to usage of 崩し字 and 旧字体 they are impossible to read.

Are there free online resources available that have original scanned/photographed books alongside with their transcripted text?

I am probably using the wrong search terms as I can't seem to find anything except [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odCXaEuz_nU).

Comment: For whatever reason, we've decided to keep our resource questions on the Meta site, so I moved your question there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"original scanned/photographed books alongside with their transcripted text"に[直接]{ちょくせつ}[応]{こた}えることはできませんが、ＯＰの[質問]｛しつもん｝は「[草双紙]｛くさぞうし｝の[文字]｛もじ｝を[読]｛よ｝みたい」という[要望]｛ようぼう｝に[起因]｛きいん｝していると[理解]｛りかい｝しました。[従]{したが}って[次]{つぎ}のような[情報]{じょうほう}を[提供]{ていきょう}します。

1.　[草双紙]{くさぞうし}を[読]｛よ｝みたいのであれば、まず[最初]{さいしょ}に、変体仮名｛へんたいがな｝（あるいは「[崩し字]{くずしじ}」、「ひらがな[旧字体]｛きゅうじたい｝」）を[読]{よ}めるようにしてください。

2.　[文献上]{ぶんけん}で[実際]{じっさい}に[使]{つか}われている変体仮名は[筆記体]{ひっきたい}（cursive, joined-up writing）で[書]{か}かれています。[一文字]{ひともじ}ずつが[分離]{ぶんり}して書かれるブロック[体]{たい}（block letters）ではないので読むのは[大変]{たいへん}[難]{むずか}しいと[思]{おも}います。

3.　実際の草双紙に書かれた変体仮名は、[文字]{もじ}が[小]{ちい}さく、また、[作成]{さくせい}されてから[時間]{じかん}も[経過]{けいか}していますので、[鮮明]{せんめい}でなく、[更]{さら}に読みにくいと思います。実際には、[私]{わたし}を[含]{ふく}めてほとんどの[日本人]{にほんじん}は、変体仮名で書かれた[文章]{ぶんしょう}や草双紙を読めません。
user30328さんは、私が[提供]{ていきょう}する[情報]{じょうほう}をヒントにして、[勉強]{べんきょう}し、草双紙[研究]{けんきゅう}の[大家]{たいか}になってください。

4.　変体仮名は、[字母]{じぼ}（変体仮名の[元]{もと}になった[漢字]{かんじ}）が[何種類]{なんしゅるい}もありますので、[現代]{げんだい}のひらがなの[何]{なに}に[該当]{がいとう}するのかを[調]{しら}べるは[面倒]{めんどう}ですが、[次]{つぎ}のところで調べることができます。

4.1　http://www10.plala.or.jp/koin/koinhentaigana.html#si
4.2　http://www.book-seishindo.jp/kana/index.html
4.3　http://www.book-seishindo.jp/kana/onjun_1.html#a
4.4　変体がな入門 単行本　https://goo.gl/D92bvy
4.5　書体字典 かな―付・名家作品集 [単行本]　https://goo.gl/6H9YWN

5.　変体仮名が[使]{つか}われる[文章]{ぶんしょう}では、[同]{おな}じ[字]{じ}が[続]{つづ}くときに一字だけ[書]{か}き、[繰]{く}り[返]{かえ}しを[表]{あらわ}す[記号]{きごう}を[付]{つ}け[足]{た}すことが[良]{よ}く[行]{おこな}われています。[日本語]{にほんご}では「[踊]{おど}り字」、[英語]{えいご}ではIteration markと[言]{い}います。草双紙でも踊り字が良く使われています。
次のところで[詳]{くわ}しく[説明]{せつめい}されています。

5.1　https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B8%8A%E3%82%8A%E5%AD%97
5.2　https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration_mark

6.　次のところに、変体仮名で書かれた文章がたくさん[紹介]{しょうかい}されています。ここでは、変体仮名の一文字ごとの読み[方]{かた}が[丁寧]{ていねい}に説明されていますので読み方を[勉強]{べんきょう}するのに[好都合]{こうつごう}です。
たくさんの文章の[内]{うち}、「草双紙」は文字が[不鮮明]{ふせんめい}ですが、「[都々逸]{どどいつ}（１）」から「都々逸（４）」は文字が鮮明ですので、最初は「都々逸」で勉強することを[勧]{すす}めます。

http://hikog.gokenin.com/edojidainohentaigana.html

7.　以下に、「都々逸（１）」の[資料]{しりょう}に[対]{たい}して説明を[追加]{ついか}します。

[image]